# Angular 5 Schematics Templating

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-schematics

So, recently my team started to try out the new schematics that comes with the latest angular-cli and decided to construct some of our own. So far it's been going smooth but now we are at a crossroad where we have no idea of where to go.

We have a json file with some data which we would like to parse and generate a custom form for. Usually when you template the files you use:

`<%= optionalFunc(someParam) %>`

However, it seems that this type of templating only handles strings, booleans and parhaps integers. Any ideas of what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Instead of templating an entire object, I simply used the EJS Teamplating rules (used by angular-schematics) to template field-by-field in an array of key-value pairs.